# Syntax for SQL Server when either of parameter is passed

Tags: sql, sql-server

If one of the paramater is passed / or both passed how to match that to single column in WHERE clause.

If both are passed should get result set just with the first one else with second one.

Ex:

```
--either will be passed
declare @processStepID int = null
declare @PROCESS_StepID int = null

if(@processStepID is null)
select * from CTL.CTRL.CTRL_PROCESS_STEP_ACTIVITIES 
where PROCESS_STEP_ID = @PROCESS_StepID
else
select * from CTL.CTRL.CTRL_PROCESS_STEP_ACTIVITIES 
where PROCESS_STEP_ID = @processStepID
```

How can this be written in where clause not using if statement.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WHERE PROCESS_STEP_ID = coalesce( @processStepID, @PROCESS_StepID )
```

Comment: +1: COALESCE is preferrable over db specific null check syntax

Answer (score 1):

Use the [ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933210(SQL.80).aspx) function

```
SELECT *
FROM CTL.CTRL.CTRL_PROCESS_STEP_ACTIVITIES 
WHERE PROCESS_STEP_ID = ISNULL( @processStepID, @PROCESS_StepID )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from CTL.CTRL.CTRL_PROCESS_STEP_ACTIVITIES 
where (PROCESS_STEP_ID = @PROCESS_StepID) OR (PROCESS_STEP_ID = @processStepID)
```

Seems far too obvious. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from CTL.CTRL.CTRL_PROCESS_STEP_ACTIVITIES 
where PROCESS_STEP_ID = ISNULL(@PROCESS_StepID,@processStepID)
```

This should do what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks Irwin. Incase both are passed i should be able to get resultset based on @processStepID.